# ADO.NET Entity Data Model - Duplicates

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

How can I add a Unqiue index to a column like in SQL, so it wont allow duplicates in the column?

Answer (score 0):

1. Double click your EDMX file. the entity model designer gui comes up.
2. Add one or more Entities if you don't have any already.
3. Select a field in an entity, and double-click it. The field property window should open up.
4. Select the property "ENTITY KEY" and set it to True.

As far as I understood, this makes the field unique.

Cheers,
G.